# Enum with methods for functionality (Combine Class / Enum)

Tags: c#

I may miss some sort of point here, if that's the case - please include that discussion as a part of my question :).

This is a shortened down and renamed sample of a working code. The `GetTicks(…)` is a single sample, which could be any sort of functionality (value of `> 0 < 9` should return a specific Enum a.so).

```
public static class Something
{
    public enum TypeOf : short
    {
        Minute = 2, Hour = 3, Day = 4, …
    }

    public static long GetTicks(Something.TypeOf someEnum)
    {
        long ticks = 0;
        switch (someEnum)
        {
            case Something.TypeOf.Minute:
                ticks = TimeSpan.TicksPerMinute;
                break;
            case Something.TypeOf.Hour:
                ticks = TimeSpan.TicksPerHour;
                break;
         ....
        }
        return ticks;
    }
}

// This class is called from anywhere in the system.
public static void SomeMethod(string dodo, object o, Something.TypeOf period)
{
    // With the design above
    long ticks = Something.GetTicks(period);

    // Traditional, if there was a simple enum
    if (period == Something.Day)
        ticks = TimeSpan.FromDays(1).Ticks;
    else if (period == Something.Hour)
        ticks = TimeSpan.FromHours(1).Ticks;
}
```

The idea is to collect functionality that concerns an `enum`, near as possible to the `enum` itself. The `enum` is the reason function. Also, I find it easy and natural to look for such functionality near the `enum`. Also, it's easy to modify or extend.

The drawback I have is that I have to state the `enum` more explicit, like `Something.TypeOf`. The design may look non-standard? And would it apply, if the `enum` was for internal use in the class.

How would you do this more nicely? 
I tried `abstract`, base inheritance, `partial`. None of them seem to apply.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

C# enums don't work well like this. However, you can implement your own "fixed set of values" fairly easily:

```
public sealed class Foo
{
    public static readonly Foo FirstValue = new Foo(...);
    public static readonly Foo SecondValue = new Foo(...);

    private Foo(...)
    {
    }

    // Add methods here
}
```

As it happens, one example I've got of this is remarkably similar to yours - [`DateTimeFieldType`](https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime/blob/1.1.1/src/NodaTime/Fields/DateTimeFieldType.cs) in [Noda Time](https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime). Sometimes you might even want to make the class unsealed, but keep the private constructor - which allows you to create subclasses *only as nested classes*. Very handy for restricting inheritance.

The downside is that you can't use switch :(

Comment: Fully indeed, ramarkably alike! I like your approach and will dig into it later when I can aware time for optimize and understand it's benefits (if some) ;)).

Comment: Yeah, Java-like enums. Though I'd recommend using a structure, not a class. And a _Value_ field for fast comparing and the switch statement.

Comment: @IllidanS4: I see no particular to use a struct - and a class allows for different subclasses implementing different behaviour (just like Java enums). Additionally, a struct would mean `default(Foo)` was always a "real" value, which can be a pain in the neck. While I'm sure there are cases where a struct version would be appropriate, I more often use classes.

Comment: Another downside is that you cannot use enumerate easily through instances of this class, correct?

Comment: @AndreiI: Not without adding something to do that - which wouldn't be too hard, of course.

Comment: @JonSkeet It is not hard, but error-prone: one would easily introduce a bug if forgets to add a new instance to the list...

Comment: @Andrei: True. I'd probably write a unit test to verify it with reflection :)

Comment: Why would one use this accepted answer's approach over providing extension methods to the Enum class? I am just wondering for my own knowledge. It seems to offer the exact same functionality.

Comment: @RichieEpiscopo: With the enum, you'd still only have that single value. So *implementing* those extension methods may well be a pain; you can't use any of the normal OO techniques, or have any state etc.

Answer (score 74):

If you don't mind a little more writing you can make extension methods to expand the interface of the `enum`.

e.g.

```
public enum TimeUnit
{
   Second,
   Minute,
   Hour,
   Day,
   Year,
   /* etc */
}
public static class TimeUnitExtensions
{
    public static long InTicks(this TimeUnit myUnit)
    {
         switch(myUnit)
         {
           case TimeUnit.Second:
               return TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond;
           case TimeUnit.Minute:
               return TimeSpan.TicksPerMinute;
            /* etc */
         }
    }
}
```

This can add "instance" methods to your enums. It's a bit more verbose than mostly liked, though.

Remember though that an `enum` should be treated mostly as a named value.

Comment: How do you tie `TimeUnitExtensions` to `TimeUnit` and the `TimeSpan` instance for which you want the ticks? I may be missing some context and no doubt my lack of C# knowledge isn't helping.

Comment: @DavidHarkness, it's because of the "this" in this line:
public static long InTicks(this TimeUnit myUnit). The "this" associate TimeUnit to extension.

Comment: I like Jon's answer, but this is a possibility as well. +1, I hadn't considered Extension methods for this!

Comment: This one combines the fastness of enums with the elegance of extension methods. Too bad there aren't extension properties. ☹