# Is there a way to implement unary operators for enum types?

Tags: c#, enums, operators, unary-operator

I have the following:

```
MovingDirection.UP;
```

and I want to use the ! operator as follows:

```
!MovingDirection.Up; // will give MovingDirection.Down
```

(it's an Enum)

I have tried:

```
public static MovingDirection operator !(MovingDirection f)
{
    return MovingDirection.DOWN;
}
```

... but I receive an error:

> Parameter type of this unary operator must be the containing type

Any ideas?

Comment: This will not work with an enum the way you are doing it!

Comment: I'd use a static class instead.

Comment: Does this need to support other directions besides up/down (such as left/right)?

Comment: I would have used `-` rather than `!`... but anyway, it's not possible, so the point is moot

Comment: @ThomasLevesque Or `~` which is the bitwise negation. All of these three unary operators are a kind of negation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you can't implement methods or operators on `enum`s. You can create an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx):

```
public static MovingDirection Reverse(this MovingDirection direction)
{
    // implement
}
```

Use like:

```
MovingDirection.Up.Reverse(); // will give MovingDirection.Down
```

Or you can use an [`enum`-like `class`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7443192/781792) instead of an actual `enum`.

Comment: Yep, that's a good workaround

Comment: Yes, a very elegant solution. I wish I had thought of that :)

Comment: i need to create a class instead of an enum?

Comment: No, but you can. It depends on what you want to achieve. Give us more infos and you'l get more detailed answers ;).

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
private bool isMovingUp(MovingDirection value)
{
    if (value == MovingDirection.UP)
        return true;
     else
        return false;
}
```

and vice versa if you like.

Or use a bool as Guthwulf said.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, this could be possible with extension methods, but unfortunatelly MS decided to not implement this feaure:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/168224/linq-cannot-implement-operator-overloading-as-extension-method

So it is either boolean if you have only up/down, or some methos IsUp(), IsDown(), ....

Answer (score 0):

You could do numeric or bitwise operations on the enum value, since enums are ints.

**Note**: *This is not necessarily a good idea.* Might not even be good. But shows another way to think of enums.

```
MovingDirection md = MovingDirection.*; // Some value
md += 1; // If it cannot be cast back to MovingDirection, then it is the default or first value aka 0 (like overflow)
(int)md & 1; // Or do some bitwise operands, like `~` to negate
```

---

edit: to show the enum and its int values

```
enum MovingDirection { UP = 0, DOWN = 1 }
```

Comment: This is not a good solution for such a simple task. Why make it complicated if you can make it easy?

Comment: @user1567896 OP is not keeping it simple. He wanted to complicate matters, he knows he can overload operands so he clearly did not want just `if(x) y; else z;`  So he got another option if he wishes.  I wouldn't expect or hope to get my answer picked as The answer, just providing another concept.

Comment: Ok, good point. But I think OP is not an experienced programmer, so it is better to keep it simple and point him to the right direction. I don't think that he knows the best way to achieve his goal.

Comment: @user1567896 Added a disclaimer!

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but it works:

`enum MovingDirection : byte { Up = 255, Down = 0 };`

```
MovingDirection t1 = MovingDirection.Up;
MovingDirection t2 = (~t1);
```